# adding object values from a model in an array list

Tags: java, arrays

If I call the setters of my model by instantiating an object as such:

```
           InterQuartileRange iq = new InterQuartileRange();
            iq.setMin(1);
            iq.setQ1(2);
            iq.setMedian(3);
            iq.setQ3(4);
            iq.setMax(5);
```

Is there a way for me to store these in an array list by calling getMin, getQ1 etc, and then printing the contents of that array list? I can't find information on whether this is possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there some reason that the underlying storage needs to be an ArrayList? You already have members on the object for each of these, right?

Comment: I want to return a list and assumed an array list would be the right way to go. It doesn't have to be an array list if there are better alternatives?

Comment: As per my understanding you want to use same object class with an ArrayList as a member (which can be accessed using get and set right).?

Comment: You said in your question that you wanted to _print_ this. Does that mean you want those 5 variables printed to the console? This can be accomplished without accumulating them into a list structure of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question asks how to *print* these values, I propose that you do *not* need to accumulate the fields into a list structure. You already have storage allocated for them (i.e. these numbers are already stored in fields), so we can create a *string* from those fields directly.

Assuming you own the class `InterQuartileRange`, add this method to it (I am guessing the internal names and types of your fields; I assume they are all `int`s):

```
public String serialize() {
    return String.format(
        "%d %d %d %d %d",
        this.min,
        this.q1,
        this.median,
        this.q3,
        this.max
        );
}
```

This composes a string from your several numbers.

Then some consumer can print that string to the console like so:

```
System.out.println(myInterQuartileRange.serialize());
```